# Get all p tags with Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to get all paragraph tags from a website using Puppeteer and later extract the text from it. `pTags`, however, is always an empty array and I have no clue why.

Here is my code.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.newyorker.com/news/letter-from-trumps-washington/the-worst-hour-of-his-entire-life-cohen-manafort-and-the-twin-courtroom-dramas-that-changed-trumps-presidency');

  const pTags = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('p')));

  console.log(pTags);

  browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the [Official Documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args):

> If the function passed to the `page.evaluate` returns a non-[Serializable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description) value, then `page.evaluate` resolves to `undefined`.

You are attempting to return a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) (a non-[Serializable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description) value) via [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), and therefore, your [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) function is returning [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined).

Instead, you can obtain an [`ElementHandle`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle) array of `p` elements using [`page.$$()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselector-1) or [`page.$x()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagexexpression):

```
const pTags = await page.$$('p');
const pTags = await page.$x('//p');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
const pTags = await page.$$("p");
```

Reference: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.7.0/docs/api.md#pageselector-1